# Disable button after one click per user per post

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery

Can someone suggest some possible solution to how do I achieve the following in WordPress?

I have a custom post type named **Deals**. On each deal page, I want to have a button which upon clicking will show some *coupon code* on the popup and then that button will be disabled for that particular user forever.

I know how to create a button and show popup, but what will be the way to disable it for that particular user after that?

Comment: Is the user logged in?

Comment: Yes, the button is visible and functionable only for logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a user meta entry to store the information that this user has received the coupon already. Then check this user meta before you print the button:

Plugin code:

```php
function coupon_button()
{
    $post_id          = get_the_ID();
    $user_id          = get_current_user_id();
    $coupons_received = (array) get_user_meta( $user_id, 'coupons_received', true );

    if ( in_array( $post_id, $coupons_received ) )
        return '';

    return get_submit_button( 'Get Coupon', '' );
}

function update_coupon_status()
{
    $user_id            = get_current_user_id();
    $coupons_received   = (array) get_user_meta( $user_id, 'coupons_received', true );
    $coupons_received[] = get_the_ID();
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'coupons_received', $coupons_received );
}
```

Template code:

```
print coupon_button();
```

And when you show the coupon, use the update function:

```
update_coupon_status();
```

Comment: but with this, the meta value will be updated globally for all posts. I want it to work on per post basis. So if user clicked button on Post A, only the button of Post A will be disabled. The button on post B should still be enabled.

Comment: @vipworks Indeed, my bad. :) See my update.

Comment: Thanks fuxia ! Looks like this will work.. I will try this.